# Speed up left-anchored query using indexes?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I havea table with users in which I'll be having a lot of username searches, i.e.

```
WHERE username LIKE 'xxx%'
```

Here's the structure of my testing database:

```
CREATE TABLE usernames
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  username character varying(64),
  name character varying(64)
)
```

I inserted one million different-ish names and usernames. I then tried to seach for a name and username without creating indexes for the two colums - the average times for the query:

```
SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE username LIKE 'xxx%'
```

is 650ms. After that I created an index for the username column using:

```
CREATE INDEX usernames_lower_idx
  ON usernames
  USING btree
  (lower(username::text)
```

And the times are again, on average 650ms. I tried with and without the `lower` function, same results. Any ideas how can I speed things up (without using an external search engine)? I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.

**EDIT 1:**

```
"Seq Scan on usernames  (cost=0.00..24437.47 rows=95 width=64) (actual time=609.796..609.796 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Filter: ((username)::text ~~ 'asd%'::text)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 998358"
"Total runtime: 609.897 ms"
```

Comment: Maybe include the output from `EXPLAIN` to help us see what is going on.

Comment: Also: ensure you have read the info on [opclasses](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-opclass.html)

Comment: I would suggest [this related answer on dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql/10696#10696).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create index usernames_idx on usernames (username varchar_pattern_ops);

analyze usernames;
```

Comment: That solved it, thanks. Now the search time for a 'xx%' query is like 15ms.